# Heroku local and remote repo's different name

Tags: git, heroku

I initialized a local heroku repo inside my project folder and it gave some random name. I didn't want that name so I renamed the app name in the remote heroku website to my project folder name. But now if I want to add some addons from commandline it(heroku) always looks for the old name & comes out with error saying ' old-name app not found'.

I copied the old-name though it doesnt exist physically (only inside the heroku config, I dont know where it is so I could modify manually) and tried the `heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname`

So I want to delete my local heroku initialization inside my project folder & do it again from start. Guide me please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku will, if one is not explicitly specified with `--app`, [attempt to determine the app name by looking at the git remotes](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/base.rb#L181).

[`heroku apps:rename` will handle updating your repository's remotes for you](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb#L231), but as you'll observe, doing it via the site will mean you'll need to update your [git remotes](http://gitref.org/remotes/) manually (you'll need to do that anyway if you have other clones)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution.

I renamed my remore heroku repo to the old-name and did the renaming using commandline with

`heroku apps:rename "new-name" --app "old-name"`

And its done!

But I want to know where heroku was looking locally as it was able to see the old name and still was thinking it was the name, in otherwords I would like to know where/ which file does heroku store the local name of the project.